# Получить из html словарь

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

помогите пожалуйста написать xpath-выражение(или несколько) которое преобразовало бы следующий html

```
<div class="TabItem">
    <p><strong>Product Composition</strong></p>
    <p>93% Polyamide 7% Elastane</p>
    <p>Lining: 100% Polyester</p><p>Dress Length: 90 cm</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>
</div>
```

в словарь вида:

```
data['Product Composition'] = '93% Polyamide 7% Elastane Lining: 100% Polyester Dress Length: 90 cm'
data['Product Attributes;'] = ': Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side Lining Type: Full Lining'
```

проблема ещё в том, что количество тэгов может быть различным.

так же буду благодарен за любой пинок в нужном направлении

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример того, что вы хотите.
Если что то не понятно - пишите, я поясню.

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

html = """
<div class="TabItem">
    <p><strong>Product Composition</strong></p>
    <p>93% Polyamide 7% Elastane</p>
    <p>Lining: 100% Polyester</p>
    <p>Dress Length: 90 cm</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes 1;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes 2;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes 3;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>

    <p><strong>Product Attributes 4;</strong></p>
    <p>: Boat Neck, Long Sleeve, Midi, Zip, Concealed, Laced, Side</p>
    <p>Lining Type: Full Lining</p>
</div>"""

tree = fromstring(html)

# получим все <p> одним списком
items = tree.xpath('//div[@class="TabItem"]/p')

# составим список номеров <p> содержащих <strong>
group_map = [x[0] for x in filter(lambda x: x[1], enumerate([bool(x.xpath('strong')) for x in items]))]

# разобьем список всех <p> на группы
groups = []
for i, index in enumerate(group_map):
    if i < len(group_map) - 1:
        groups.append(items[group_map[i]:group_map[i+1]])
    else:
        groups.append(items[group_map[i]:])

# превратим список групп в нужный словарь
result = dict([(x[0].xpath('strong')[0].text, ' '.join(map(lambda x: x.text, x[1:]))) for x in groups])

print result
```